# linux find more than one -exec

Tags: bash, sed, find, exec

`find . -iname "*.txt" -exec program '{}' \; | sed 's/Value= //'`

-"program" returns a different value for each file, and the output is prefixed with `"Value= "`

In this time the output will be `"Value= 128"` and the after sed just `128`.

How can I take just the value `"128"` and have the input file be renamed to `128`.txt
but also have this find run thought multiple files.

sorry for bad descriptions.
I will try to clear if needed

Answer (score 0):

First write a shell script capable of renaming an argument:

```
mv "$1" "$(program "$1" | sed "s/Value= //").txt"
```

Then embed that script in your find command:

```
find . -iname "*.txt" \
    -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "$(program "$1" | sed "s/Value= //").txt"' _ {} \;
```